# GStreamer video in QML plugin

Tags: gstreamer, qml, meego

I want to display video via GStreamer in QML plugin. Currently video is displayed on top of all widgets (on top of all applications).

So, I have QML plugin which uses QGraphicsProxyWidget to display player inherited from QGst::Ui::VideoWidget. After setting up pipeline and video sink as qwidgetvideosink video is played on top of all widgets/applications.

How can I output it in QGst::Ui::VideoWidget bounds?

Comment: Can you post how you solved it please?

Comment: I would be also very happy to see some solution of this problem. Would you mind how you've got wrapped GStreamer within QML plugin? I'm stuck at trying to get QGraphicsView from within QDeclarativeItem.